# ArcGIS - Need help with Layout View talk

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I'm giving a talk tomorrow on using Layout View.
I know a fair amount of tricks to make things easier/neater.

I'm looking for solid tips to help a newish user with making a better layout.

I've got things like using snap guides, service layer credits, changing legends to more reader friendly, toggling draft mode (to reduce drawing/find what each of your data layers are), changing scale bars to be more reader friendly.

Comment: The new dynamic text elements available are very useful in some situations (ex: not having to change the "last updated" date every time you print a new version of a map).  Also, many navigation shortcuts from data view, work on the layout view also, ex: hold down Z key and it temporarily changes the  cursor to the zoom-in cursor (left mouse click & drag creates a zoom in area if Z key is pressed), similarly clicking with or pressing down on (not scrolling) on the center scroll bar, if available with your mouse, temp changes the cursor to the layout pan tool.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the two temp changes ones.

Answer (score 1):

10.2 Customize>Customize Mode and select Page Layout and you will see many more tools that you can use in the Page Layout view.

Example Polygon Text > Spline Text > Rotate Layout

[image]

Comment: Counter point: I use the 'Drawing' toolbar for most of those.

Comment: but there are extra tools not displayed in the drawing tool bar

Comment: I did find the extra handy eyedropper tool I have always wanted and didn't know existed.